# What's the most common reason for ModalInstanceCtrl to give this error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to hook up an Angular Bootstrap modal (pop-up) but it's giving me either "templateUrl" not found error, or this error: Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=ModalInstanceCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

I just want some theoretical suggestions on why that would be the case. I have tried a lot of things: it's all properly hooked up, all the spelling matches, etc, etc.

$modal is being used in the controller with other functions as well, so it's all being injected.

Comment: One reason could be the JS file having controller's definition is not included. For error "Argument 'ModalInstanceCtrl' is not a function, got undefined", it points to non availability of the function, which could be because of incorrect path or non inclusion of file. Can you share your directory structure and paths that you have specified?

Comment: The template that you're trying to load has a controller mapping to it, but the corresponding javascript file for the controller is not loaded in the main index.html file..

Comment: @Yashika Garg: about non-availability of the function: it actually calls it because it gets the console log from it.

Comment: @VarvaraJones Please share the directory structure and paths that you have specified?

Comment: @YashikaGarg thanks a lot for trying to help! I just tried something and figured it out!

Comment: @Techac9iac: thanks a lot for trying to help! I just tried something and figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

Angular Documents provide a suggestion that when you get this error it is possible that you have a controller being injected into another controller. Which is exactly what was happening with my attempt to add a modal as their box solution:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

});
```

**controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'** MUST BE removed from your modal function if you're adding it to an existing controller, otherwise it will all go to ... you know where.

Answer (score 0):

Can be as simple as the **controller** not existing on your **module**.

I forgot to add the code for the modal controller :( when I first tried it in my project

This controller is about 3 controllers deep in my project (make sure your using "controller **AS** cntlr" style) so embedding wasn't a problem for me.

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {
    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.selected = {
        item: $scope.items[0]
    };

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```